# Measurable function on Hilbert space

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Every continuous function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable. Is it also true in Hilbert spaces ? any references are there?

Comment: Inverse image commutes with intersections, unions and complements. The Borel sigma algebra is generated by open sets and continuous functions are defined so that inverse images of open sets are open.

Answer (score 1):

Any continuous map from one topological sapce to another is Borel measurable in the sense inverse image of any Borel set is  Borel set.

Comment: Thanq sir. Please suggest  any reference books

Comment: If you are keen on knowing more about various types of measurability and integrability for Banach valued functions you can read Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: thanq sir. It may be helpful